# Three FOR loops in ampscript after reading from XML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop

I have an eReceipt issue. I am able to get the nested loop to work to display the promo amounts and descriptions when there is only one promo per item purchased. Where I am stuck is trying to add a third loop to account for the scenario where there are multiple promos PER item. How and where would I add this additional loop? Here is an XML sample and below that is my current code. Thank you!

```
<eReceiptPOS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <receiptHeader>
    <storeAddress>2901 W AGUA FRIA FWY</storeAddress>
    <storeCity>PHOENIX</storeCity>
    <storeState>AZ</storeState>
    <storePostalCode>85027</storePostalCode>
    <storePhoneNumber>6234929045</storePhoneNumber>
  </receiptHeader>
  <receiptLine>
    <transactionType>Sale</transactionType>
    <itemUPC>40051521661</itemUPC>
    <itemDescription>Top Dog PLUS</itemDescription>
    <itemQuantity>1</itemQuantity>
    <itemPriceCharged>0.00</itemPriceCharged>
    <itemRequiresReturnReceipt>false</itemRequiresReturnReceipt>
    <itemRegularPrice>23.00</itemRegularPrice>
    <itemPromo>
      <itemPromoDescription>10% Off Military Discount Tuesday</itemPromoDescription>
      <itemPromoAmount>2.30</itemPromoAmount>
    </itemPromo>
    <itemLoyaltyPoints>20.70</itemLoyaltyPoints>
    <itemAllPromosTotalAmout>23.00</itemAllPromosTotalAmout>
    <itemReturnPrice>0.0</itemReturnPrice>
    <isDonation>false</isDonation>
    <itemNonTaxable>true</itemNonTaxable>
    <itemReceiptedReturn>false</itemReceiptedReturn>
  </receiptLine>
  <receiptLine>
    <transactionType>Sale</transactionType>
    <itemUPC>40050137741</itemUPC>
    <itemDescription>Top Dog</itemDescription>
    <itemQuantity>1</itemQuantity>
    <itemPriceCharged>0.00</itemPriceCharged>
    <itemRequiresReturnReceipt>false</itemRequiresReturnReceipt>
    <itemRegularPrice>18.00</itemRegularPrice>
    <itemPromo>
      <itemPromoDescription>10% Off Military Discount Tuesday</itemPromoDescription>
      <itemPromoAmount>1.80</itemPromoAmount>
    </itemPromo>
    <itemLoyaltyPoints>16.20</itemLoyaltyPoints>
    <itemAllPromosTotalAmout>18.00</itemAllPromosTotalAmout>
    <itemReturnPrice>0.0</itemReturnPrice>
    <isDonation>false</isDonation>
    <itemNonTaxable>true</itemNonTaxable>
    <itemReceiptedReturn>false</itemReceiptedReturn>
  </receiptLine>
  <receiptLine>
    <transactionType>Sale</transactionType>
    <itemUPC>40050067261</itemUPC>
    <itemDescription>AUSTRALIAN CATTLE DOG B&amp;T</itemDescription>
    <itemQuantity>1</itemQuantity>
    <itemPriceCharged>0.00</itemPriceCharged>
    <itemRequiresReturnReceipt>false</itemRequiresReturnReceipt>
    <itemRegularPrice>44.00</itemRegularPrice>
    <itemPromo>
      <itemPromoDescription>Weekday Discount</itemPromoDescription>
      <itemPromoAmount>5.00</itemPromoAmount>
    </itemPromo>
    <itemPromo>
      <itemPromoDescription>10% Off Military Discount Tuesday</itemPromoDescription>
      <itemPromoAmount>3.90</itemPromoAmount>
    </itemPromo>
    <itemLoyaltyPoints>35.10</itemLoyaltyPoints>
    <itemAllPromosTotalAmout>44.00</itemAllPromosTotalAmout>
    <itemReturnPrice>0.0</itemReturnPrice>
    <isDonation>false</isDonation>
    <itemNonTaxable>true</itemNonTaxable>
    <itemReceiptedReturn>false</itemReceiptedReturn>
  </receiptLine>
  <receiptSummary>
    <subTotalAmount>0.00</subTotalAmount>
    <taxableAmount>0.0</taxableAmount>
    <nonTaxableAmount>0.0</nonTaxableAmount>
    <taxRate>0.0</taxRate>
    <taxUSAmount>0.0</taxUSAmount>
    <totalAmount>0.00</totalAmount>
    <tenderedAmount>0</tenderedAmount>
    <tenderType>Treats account</tenderType>
    <paymentCardNumberMasked>1344808369</paymentCardNumberMasked>
    <cashChangeDue>0</cashChangeDue>
    <totalItemsSold>3</totalItemsSold>
    <totalItemsReturned>0</totalItemsReturned>
    <feeCdafc>0</feeCdafc>
    <feePifRsf>0</feePifRsf>
  </receiptSummary>
  <receiptSaleDetails>
    <receiptValidFrom>2021-09-17T08:39:37.0741524</receiptValidFrom>
    <storeNumber>0133</storeNumber>
    <tillNumber>111</tillNumber>
    <transactionNumber>70026462</transactionNumber>
    <transactionDateTime>2021-07-19T08:39:37.0741524</transactionDateTime>
  </receiptSaleDetails>
  <receiptSavingDetails>
    <loyaltyPromoSavingsTotal>85.00</loyaltyPromoSavingsTotal>
    <treatPoints>70.00</treatPoints>
    <totalSavingsPercent>100.00 %</totalSavingsPercent>
    <totalSavingsAmount>85.00</totalSavingsAmount>
    <totalRedemptionValue>9925.00</totalRedemptionValue>
  </receiptSavingDetails>
  <receiptLoyaltyDetails>
    <loyaltyID>1344808369</loyaltyID>
    <basePointsEarned>0</basePointsEarned>
    <bonusPointsEarned>0</bonusPointsEarned>
    <pointsRedeemed>28800</pointsRedeemed>
    <pointsBalance>3970820</pointsBalance>
    <pointsExpirationDate xsi:nil="true" />
  </receiptLoyaltyDetails>
</eReceiptPOS>
```

Code:

```
%%[

  set @itemNodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"eReceiptPOS/receiptLine",0)
  set @itemRowCount = rowcount(@itemNodes)

  
  if @itemRowCount > 0 THEN
  FOR @i = 1 to @itemRowCount DO
   set @itemNodePath = concat("/eReceiptPOS/receiptLine[",@i,"]/")
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemUPC'),0)) > 0 then
    set @itemUPC = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemUPC"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemDescription'),0)) > 0 then
     set @itemDesc = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemDescription"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF 
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemRegularPrice'),0)) > 0 then
     set @itemRegularPrice = FormatNumber(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemRegularPrice"),0),1),'Value'),'C2')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemReturnPrice'),0)) > 0 then
     set @itemReturnPrice = FormatNumber(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemReturnPrice"),0),1),'Value'), 'C2')
   ENDIF
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemPriceCharged'),0)) > 0 then
     set @itemPriceCharged = FormatNumber(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemPriceCharged"),0),1),'Value'), 'C2')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemQuantity'),0)) > 0 then
     SET @itemQuantity = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemQuantity"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemRegularPrice'),0)) > 0 AND not empty(@itemQuantity) then
     SET @itemMultipliedPrice = Format(Multiply(@itemQuantity, Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemRegularPrice"),0),1),'Value')), 'C2')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemLoyaltySavings'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemLoyaltySavings = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemLoyaltySavings"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemLoyaltyPoints'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @treatsPointsDiscount = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemLoyaltyPoints"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemEmployeeDiscountAmount'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemEmployeeDiscountAmount = Format(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemEmployeeDiscountAmount"),0),1),'Value'), 'C2')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemCouponAmount'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemCouponAmount = Format(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemCouponAmount"),0),1),'Value'),'C2')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemDiscountReasonCode'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemDiscountReasonCode = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemDiscountReasonCode"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemDiscountAmount'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemDiscountAmount = Format(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemDiscountAmount"),0),1),'Value'),'C2')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemGiftCardLast4Number'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    set @itemGiftCardLast4Number = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemGiftCardLast4Number"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemPrescriptionCardNumber'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    set @itemPrescriptionCardNumber = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemPrescriptionCardNumber"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemTrainingDate'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    set @itemTrainingDate = Format(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemTrainingDate"),0),1),'Value'),'MM/dd/yyyy')
   ENDIF
        ]%%

        
              %%[IF not empty(@itemUPC) or not empty(@itemDesc) or not empty(@itemPriceCharged) then]%%
                    %%[if not empty(@itemUPC) then]%%
                    %%=v(@itemUPC)=%%
                    %%[ENDIF]%%
                    %%[if not empty(@itemDesc) then]%%
                    <br> %%=v(@itemDesc)=%%
                    %%[endif]%%

                %%[IF not empty(@itemPriceCharged) then]%%
                  %%=v(@itemPriceCharged)=%%
                %%[endif]%% 

              %%[ENDIF]%%

                      %%[IF not empty(@itemQuantity) AND not empty(@itemRegularPrice) then]%%

                        reg. price (%%=v(@itemQuantity)=%% @ %%=v(@itemRegularPrice)=%%)
                        %%=v(@itemMultipliedPrice)=%%
                      %%[endif]%%
                      
   %%[IF not empty(@itemDiscountReasonCode) OR not empty(@itemDiscountAmount) THEN]%%]
                        %%=concat('(',Format(@itemDiscountAmount, 'C2'),')')=%%
                   
                      %%[ENDIF]%%
                      
                      
                      
                   
                      
                      %%[IF not empty(@itemLoyaltySavings) THEN]%%
                        treats savings
                        %%=concat('(',Format(@itemLoyaltySavings, 'C2'),')')=%%
                   
                      %%[ENDIF]%%
                      
                    %%[IF not empty(@treatsPointsDiscount) THEN]%%
                        treats points
                        %%=concat('(',Format(@treatsPointsDiscount, 'C2'),')')=%%                    
                      %%[ENDIF]%%
                      
                      %%[IF not empty(@itemEmployeeDiscountAmount) THEN]%%
                        associate discount
                        %%=concat('(',Format(@itemEmployeeDiscountAmount, 'C2'),')')=%%

                      %%[ENDIF]%%
                      
                         %%[IF not empty(@itemCouponAmount) THEN]%%
                        coupon amount]
                        %%=concat('(',Format(@itemCouponAmount, 'C2'),')')=%%
                      %%[ENDIF]%%
                      
                      
                      
   %%[
   
  set @itemPromoNodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"eReceiptPOS/receiptLine/itemPromo",0)
  set @itemPromoRowCount = rowcount(@itemPromoNodes)
  
  if @itemPromoRowCount > 0 THEN
  FOR @j = 1 to @itemPromoRowCount DO
   set @itemPromoNodePath = concat("/eReceiptPOS/receiptLine[",@i,"]/itemPromo/")
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemPromoNodePath,'itemPromoAmount'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemPromoAmount = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemPromoNodePath,"itemPromoAmount"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
   IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemPromoNodePath,'itemPromoDescription'), 0)) > 0 THEN
    SET @itemPromoDescription = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemPromoNodePath,"itemPromoDescription"),0),1),'Value')
   ENDIF
   
next @j endif
   ]%%
   
   %%[IF not empty(@itemPromoAmount) AND not empty(@itemPromoDescription) THEN]%%         


                        %%=v(@itemPromoDescription)=%%
                        %%=concat('(',Format(@itemPromoAmount, 'C2'),')')=%%
            
%%[ENDIF]%%
                      
                              
                      
                      
                      %%[if not empty(@itemGiftCardLast4Number) then]%%
                        gift card
                        %%=v(@itemGiftCardLast4Number)=%%
                      %%[endif]%%
                      
                      
                       %%[if not empty(@itemPrescriptionCardNumber) then]%%
                        %%=v(@itemPrescriptionCardNumber)=%%

                      %%[endif]%%
                      
                      %%[if not empty(@itemTrainingDate) then]%%
                        training date
                        %%=v(@itemTrainingDate)=%%

                      %%[endif]%%

                %%[if not empty(@itemReturnprice) then]%%
                        return price
                        %%=v(@itemReturnPrice)=%% each
                      %%[endif]%%


        %%[next @i endif]%%
```

@adam-spriggs

Comment: @adamspriggs Please see my response.

Answer (score 2):

Your promo code output wasn't inside your secondary loop.

I'd suggest that you start simple and get your code indented.  Makes it much easier to get your loops correct.

```
%%[

set @itemNodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"eReceiptPOS/receiptLine",0)
set @itemRowCount = rowcount(@itemNodes)

if @itemRowCount > 0 THEN

    FOR @i = 1 to @itemRowCount DO

        set @itemNodePath = concat("/eReceiptPOS/receiptLine[",@i,"]/")

        IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,'/itemUPC'),0)) > 0 then
            set @itemUPC = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemNodePath,"itemUPC"),0),1),'Value')
        ENDIF

        ]%%

            %%[ if not empty(@itemUPC) then ]%%
              <br>%%=v(@itemUPC)=%%
            %%[ ENDIF ]%%

        %%[

        set @itemPromoNodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("eReceiptPOS/receiptLine[", @i, "]/itemPromo"),0)
        set @itemPromoRowCount = rowcount(@itemPromoNodes)

        if @itemPromoRowCount > 0 THEN

            FOR @j = 1 to @itemPromoRowCount DO

              set @itemPromoNodePath = concat("/eReceiptPOS/receiptLine[",@i,"]/itemPromo[", @j, "]/")

              IF rowCount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemPromoNodePath,'itemPromoAmount'), 0)) > 0 THEN
                set @itemPromoAmount = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@itemPromoNodePath,"itemPromoAmount"),0),1),'Value')
              ENDIF

              ]%%

                  %%[ IF not empty(@itemPromoAmount)THEN ]%%         
                    <br>%%=concat('(',Format(@itemPromoAmount, 'C2'),')')=%%
                  %%[ ENDIF ]%%

              %%[
              
            next @j 

        endif
        ]%%


    %%[
    next @i
    ]%% 
%%[
endif
]%%
```

Once you've got your structure, add the additional variables and HTML.

[image: loops]

I'm using [Sublime Text 4](https://www.sublimetext.com/download) as my editor and the [AMPscript Syntax Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AMPscript%20Syntax%20Highlighter) extension.

Just pasting it back into Content Builder once it's indented.

Comment: I am now getting this error: **The function call includes more parameters than the maximum allowed for the function Function Call: BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"eReceiptPOS/receiptLine[",@i,"]/itemPromo",0)** @adam spriggs

Comment: Updated.  Forgot a concat on line 24

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! @adam